Would like to test for WHERE ISTEXT() in a Sheets Query
I have a data table with a "values" column that has the values:

TRUE
FALSE
string of text
blank

I'd like to do something that works like this:
=query(database,"select Col4,Col5,Col8 where istext(Col8) ")
I guess I can use Col8 matches 'something' but I don't know regular expressions well enough to specify a text string.
thoughts?
I tried =query(database,"select Col4,Col5,Col8 where istext(Col8) ")
and was expecting istext() to produce true or false.

Post few of your sample data.

QUERY doesn't have a built-in istext() function, and if it did, it would ignore the least dominant data types in the column.
I recommend using FILTER instead.
=LET(d,<data>,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(d,4,5,8),ISTEXT(INDEX(d,,8))))

Replace <data> with the range/array containing/generating your data.

You need to use the ISTEXT() function outside the SQL command. Here is a sample database and a Query which extracts the names from Column A and the relavent data in Column E if there is a "Text" in Column E
The logic is; to include a fictitious column (field) to the database and use it in the Where clause.
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:E,ISTEXT(E2:E)},"Select Col1, Col5 Where Col6=TRUE"))

.

